# Uniqueness of IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that $x''=x|x|, \quad$ $x(0)=a, \quad$ $x'(0)=b$ has a unique solution for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

I tried to show that the function is globally lipschitz, but did not succeed. And since it is continous, if it were globally lipschitz that would have worked to show uniqueness for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

In the solution sheet, they just mention that '$f(t,x)=x|x|$ has a continous first derivative'. I cant really grasp this, how is it possible to show uniqueness for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ by just arguing that 'it has continuous first derivative' ?

Comment: come on put some effort on the title man

Comment: Try to transform the equation in a system of equations of the first order, then you just need to show that for every initial condition $(0,(a,b))$ the system has an unique solution (you don't need the global existence of the solution so globally lipschitz is not needed), what theorem should you use?